# Can't set active item of BottomNavigationView while recreating app

Tags: android, android-bottom-nav-view

Can't set active item of BottomNavigationView while recreating app: the last selected item is active after recreating app, so `BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item0)` takes no visual effect, but `onNavigationItemSelected` was called succeessfully.

So how can I prevent restoring previous active item of BNV? Thanks.

Comment: Where you used `BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item0)` ?

Comment: @Ibrahim used that in `Activity.onCreate`

Comment: You should use it inside `onResume()`

Comment: @Ibrahim but in this case how can I check if app wasn't recreated but just switched foreground?

Comment: In fact, if your app recreated the selected item will be `item0` by default, I think your current behavior is when app go to the recent apps and open it again, so how you can check if app in recent app or not that's very easy.

Comment: @Ibrahim ok, going to check up this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that inside `onResume()` instead because while your *app* in the recent *apps* then the `BottomNavigationView` will always catch the position.

**Why set position not work?**

Because you set the position inside `onCreate()` which not invoked when app start from recent apps.

**How to set the position then?**

Inside in `onStart()` or `onResume()` and that will work.

**How to check if app opened from recent-apps?**

We can play with boolean e.g:

```
boolean isFromRecents = false;

onCreate(){
isFromRecents = true;
}

onResume(){
if(isFromRecents)
   //do smth
}
```